# select columns with one column has different value but repeatable

Tags: mysql, group-by, rows

I don't speak english but I'll try to explain my question:

I have this.

```
col | col 1 | col 2 | col 3
kar   a        a2      D
kar   a        a2      E
kar   a        a2      D
fer   b        b2      F
fer   b        b2      E
fer   b        b2      D
jose  a        a2      G
jose  a        a2      G
```

I need to have this result: only people that have more than one value in col3 and count how much differents values they have, something like this:

```
col | col 1 | col 2 | count
 kar     a       a2     2
 fer     b       b2     3
```

Jose is not in the result because he have an unic value in col3 column.

I have this query but I don't know how count and group de rows

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablafinal t join
     (SELECT COL1, COL2
      FROM tablafinal
      GROUP BY COL1, COL2
      HAVING COUNT(distinct COL3) > 1
     ) cols
     on t.COL1 = cols.COL1 and t.COL2 = cols.COL2
```

Result:

```
col | col 1 | col 2 | col 3
kar   a        a2      D
kar   a        a2      E
kar   a        a2      D
fer   b        b2      F
fer   b        b2      E
fer   b        b2      D
```

with group by col 3 this group to "kar" and "fer" in one row :c

I AM USING MYSQL

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT col, col1, col2, count(distinct col3) as counts
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col, col1, col2
HAVING count(distinct col3) > 1
```

Comment: don't work because "fer" and "kar" have equals values in col1 and col2 and to do the group by the data is lose

Comment: You just mentioned col3. I didnt saw col1 and 2 requirement. Please update the question with sample input, sample output and what are the considerations that you are looking for.

Comment: col1 and col2 don't have requirement but two people can have equals values in this col's; the target is find unics rows and for this I need to know who have more than one data in col3. A unic row is a combination of col1, col2 and col3.